# Processes: receiving current open

Tags: c#, .net, process

I want to troll my brother a Little bit ;) by writing a program, which I can put in his "StartUp"-Folder. This program should scan his default system tasks so that it doesn't destroy his computer so I wrote all currently open processes in a list. Now I want to check when he opens a program (Process) is it in the list("Taskmgr" is also in the list, so you can exit the troll anytime)? If the opened Process is not in the list, kill it. If you Need any further information, please ask...
My current code is this:

```
void CloseProcesses()
{
    Process[] arrProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();
    List<string> lststrProcessNames = new List<string>();

    /*Writes current running processes(+ taskmanager process) in a list*/
    foreach (Process CurrentProcess in arrProcesses)
    {
        lststrProcessNames.Add(CurrentProcess.ProcessName);
    }
    lststrProcessNames.Add("taskmgr");

    try
    {
        Process[] arrNewProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process NewCurrentProcess in arrNewProcesses)
        {
            if (lststrProcessNames.Contains(NewCurrentProcess.ProcessName))
            {
                CloseProcesses();
            }
            else
            {
                NewCurrentProcess.Kill();
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: To me I do not support malware